# SSRS - group by a column when using a parameter

Tags: sql, reporting-services, powerbi

I'm new to SSRS and I'm trying to create a paginated report. I'm trying to use a parameter to filter the results so that it contains ALL items on the same invoice, not just the item code that I specify. I cannot get values from the query as it would be too large due to the large amount of item codes in the table and it wouldn't bring all items from that invoice unless I knew what item codes were on that invoice specifically.

My table is as follows:

| Invoice # | Item Code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Item A |
| 1 | Item B |
| 1 | Item C |
| 2 | Item A |
| 3 | Item A |
| 3 | Item B |
| 3 | Item C |
| 4 | Item D |

My query is basically:

```
SELECT InvoiceNumber, ItemCode FROM InvoiceItems WHERE ItemCode = @ItemCode
```

So I've created a parameter: @ItemCode. I changed my query in the dataset so that ItemCode = @ItemCode and it works for that item.

Current Result:
Parameter @ItemCode = Item A, then it pulls up all invoices with records of Item A only. So it'll pull Item A on Invoice 1 and on Invoice 2.

| Invoice # | Item Code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Item A |
| 2 | Item A |
| 3 | Item A |

Desired Result:
For example, if parameter @ItemCode = Item A then I'd like for it to pull Item A, Item B, and Item C from that invoice which feels like some sort of basic grouping, but I can't seem to figure it out.

If the parameter is input as "Item A", the desired report output should show:

| Invoice # | Item Code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Item A |
| 1 | Item B |
| 1 | Item C |
| 2 | Item A |
| 3 | Item A |
| 3 | Item B |
| 3 | Item C |

Answer (score 0):

It's not that clear what you require but I'm assuming that if the user selects 'Item A', you want to get all data for all invoice that have 'Item A' in them?

If that's true then you would need to do something like...

```
SELECT * 
FROM Invoices
WHERE InvoiceID IN(SELECT DISTINCT InvoiceID FROM Invoices WHERE ItemCode = @ItemCode)
```

---

Updated based on OP's response

---

```
-- set up the table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #InvoiceItems

CREATE TABLE #InvoiceItems (InvoiceNumber INT, ItemCode varchar(10))
INSERT INTO #InvoiceItems VALUES 
(1, 'Item A'), (1, 'Item B'), (1, 'Item C'),
(2, 'Item A'),
(3, 'Item B'), (3, 'Item C'), (3, 'Item A'),
(4, 'Item D')

-- query 
DECLARE @ItemCode varchar(10) = 'Item A'

SELECT * 
FROM #InvoiceItems
WHERE InvoiceNumber IN(SELECT DISTINCT InvoiceNumber FROM #InvoiceItems WHERE ItemCode = @ItemCode)
ORDER BY InvoiceNumber, ItemCode
```

Here I've recreated your sample data and then run the query I originally posted (with table name updates etc). I've also added an ORDER BY clause but this would not affect the data returned.

If you run this you get the following results.

[image]

Comment: I apologize for the ambiguity, I've tried to edit and update my OP to be more descriptive. When updating my WHERE statement per your suggestion, I end up with the same issues as I do currently, where I only get the lines that contain the @ItemCode parameter, not ALL of the invoice lines.

Comment: No problem. I've added a full sample but I have not changed the logic in the query. It gives the results exactly as expected.

If this does not work, show you full query.